# como cambiar de de PHP 5 a PHP 7? mysql_query a mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Cambiar de mysql_query a mysqli_query bueno en realidad no le entiendo mucho al cambio espero me pudieras ayudar a cambiar mi consulta que estoy haciendo es para verificar la consulta de mi login les dejo el código no le entiendo muy bien al cambio por mysqli

```html
<?php
//Begin Variable
 global $config;
 include_once("config.php");
 $config["show_error"] = false;
 $config["encode_key"] = "N07EGTIGZP77xsS";
 $config["table_settings"] = "settings";
 $config["table_users"] = "users";
 $config["table_types"] = "types";
 $config["table_cards"] = "cards";
 $config["table_categorys"] = "category";
    $config["table_categorys_dump"] = "dumpcategory";
 $config["table_plans"] = "plans";
 $config["table_orders"] = "orders";
    $config["table_packs"] = "packs";
    $config["table_salepack"] = "salepack";
    $config["table_dumps"] = "dumps";
 $config["table_faq"] = "faq";
    $config["table_news"] = "news";
    $config["table_bases"] = "bases";
 $config["table_questions"] = "questions";
    $config["table_support"] = "support";
//End Variable
 
//Begin Function
 function db_connection()
{
    global $config,$data_sql;
    $data_sql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');
    // You can select the db, by passing it as 4th param if you like
    if (!$data_sql) die("Can't connect to MySql".mysqli_error($data_sql ) );

}
 function db_close()
 {
  global $data_sql;
  @mysql_close($data_sql);
 }
 function clean($str)
 {
  $str = @trim($str);
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
   $str = stripslashes($str);
  }
  return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
 }
 function is_login()
 {
  //if (session_is_registered("userId") && session_is_registered("username") && session_is_registered("regDate"))
  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
    function is_login_seller()
 {
  //if (session_is_registered("userId") && session_is_registered("username") && session_is_registered("regDate") && $_SESSION["userType"] == '3')
  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']) && ($_SESSION['userType'] == '3'))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
 function is_login_admin()
 {
  //if (session_is_registered("userId") && session_is_registered("username") && session_is_registered("regDate") && $_SESSION["userType"] == '1')
  if (isset($_SESSION['userId']) && ($_SESSION['username']) && ($_SESSION['regDate']) && ($_SESSION['userType'] == '1'))
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   @session_destroy();
   return false;
  }
 }
function sql_error()
{
 if ($config['show_error'])
 {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error($data_sql));
 }
 else
 {
  die("Error, please contact webmaster for more information.");
 }
}
//End Function
 
//Begin configuration
 if (!$config['show_error'])
 {
  error_reporting(1);
 }
 session_start();
//End configuration
 
 db_connection();
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $config["table_settings"];
 $result = mysql_query($sql,$data_sql);
 if ($result)
 {
  while ($setting = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
   $listSetting[] = $setting;
  }
  if (is_array($listSetting))
  {
   foreach($listSetting as $setting)
   {
    $config[$setting[settingName]] = $setting[settingValue];
   }
  }
  else
  {
   die("Data setting has error.");
  }
 }
 else
 {
  if ($config['show_error'])
  {
   die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error($data_sql));
  }
  else
  {
   die("Error, please contact webmaster for more information.");
  }
 }
 db_close();
?>
```

Cambiar de mysql_query a mysqli_query bueno en realidad no le entiendo mucho al cambio espero me pudieras ayudar a cambiar mi consulta que estoy haciendo es para verificar la consulta de mi login les dejo el código no le entiendo muy bien al cambio por mysqli

Comment: Tambien tienes que cambiar la conexion con la base de datos, adjunta el codigo para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Siempre puedes consultar la documentación para ver las diferencias con [`mysqli_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)